# Python struggling with data?

Tags: python, arrays, database, python-3.x

The basis of the programme is to convert postcodes(UK version of ZIP codes) into co-ordinates. So I have a file with a load of postcodes(and other attached data such as house prices) and another file with all of the UK postcodes and their correlating co-ordinates.

I turn both of these into lists and then use a for loop inside a for loop to iterate over and compare the postcodes in either file. If postcodes in file1 == postcodes in file2 then the co-ordinates are taken and appended to the relevant file.

I've got my code up and running as I want it too. All of my tests output exactly what I want which is great.

The only problem is that it will only work with small batches of data (I've been testing with .csv files holding ~100 rows - creating lists of 100 inner lists).

Now I want to apply my programme to my entire data set. I ran it once, and nothing happened. I went away, watched some tv and still nothing happened. IDLE wouldn't let me quit the programme or anything. So I restarted and tried again, this time adding in a counter to see if my code was running. I run the code and the counter starts going. Until it hits 78902, the size of my dataset. Then it stops and does nothing. I can't do anything nor can I close the window.

The annoying thing is is that it doesn't even get past reading the CSV file, so I haven't been able to manipulate my data whatsoever.

Here is the code where it gets stuck (the very first part of the code):

```
    #empty variable to put the list into    
    lst = []
    # List function enables use for all files
    def create_list():

        #find the file
        file2 = input('enter filepath:')
        #read the file and iterate over it to append into the list
        with open(file2, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                lst.append(row)
        return lst
```

So does anyone know a way for me to make my data more manageable?

EDIT: for those interested here is my full code:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
import csv

new_file = asksaveasfile()

lst = []
# List function enables use for all files
def create_list():
    #empty variable to put the list into
    #find the file
    file2 = input('enter filepath:')
    #read the file and iterate over it to append into the list
    with open(file2, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            lst.append(row)
    return lst


def remove_space(lst):
    '''(lst)->lst
    Returns the postcode value without any whitespace

    >>> ac45 6nh
    ac456nh
    The above would occur inside a list inside a list
    '''
    filetype = input('Is this a sale or crime?: ')
    num = 0
    #check the filetype to find the position of the postcodes
    if filetype == 'sale':
        num = 3
        #iterate over the postcode to add all characters but the space
    for line in range(len(lst)):        
        pc = ''
        for char in lst[line][num]:
            if char != ' ':
                pc = pc+char
        lst[line][num] = pc

def write_new_file(lst, new_file):
    '''(lst)->.CSV file
    Takes a list and writes it into a .CSV file.
    '''
    writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(lst)
    new_file.close()


#conversion function
def find_coord(postcode):

    lst = create_list()
    #create python list for conversion comparison
    print(lst[0])
    #empty variables
    long = 0
    lat = 0
    #iterate over the list of postcodes, when the right postcode is found,
    # return the co-ordinates.
    for row in lst:
        if row[1] == postcode:
            long = row[2]
            lat = row[3]
    return str(long)+' '+str(lat)

def find_all_coord(postcode, file):

    #empty variables
    long = 0
    lat = 0
    #iterate over the list of postcodes, when the right postcode is found,
    # return the co-ordinates.
    for row in file:
        if row[1] == postcode:
            long = row[2]
            lat = row[3]
    return str(long)+' '+str(lat)

def convert_postcodes():
    '''
    take a list of lst = []
    #find the file
    file2 = input('enter filepath:')
    #read the file and iterate over it to append into the list
    with open(file2, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            lst.append(row)
    '''
    #save the files into lists so that they can be used
    postcodes = []
    with open(input('enter postcode key filepath:'), 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            postcodes.append(row)
    print('enter filepath to be converted:')
    file = []
    with open(input('enter filepath to be converted:'), 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            file.append(row)
    #here is the conversion code
    long = 0
    lat = 0
    matches = 0
    for row in range(len(file)):
        for line in range(len(postcodes)):
            if file[row][3] == postcodes[line][1]:
                long = postcodes[line][2]
                lat = postcodes[line][3]
                file[row].append(str(long)+','+str(lat))
                matches = matches+1
                print(matches)
    final_file = asksaveasfile()
    write_new_file(file, final_file)
```

I call the functions individually from IDLE so I can test it before making the programme run them itself.

Comment: Can you process each row of `file2` one at a time, or do you need to load all the rows into a Python list, retained in memory all at same time?

Comment: So you are processing 78902 * 78902 comparisons?

Comment: As I'm new, it's easier for me to do each bit one at a time. However the majority of my code is based on for loops running over my code one at a time, so it sounds possible. But if I'm already failing at the first step processing wise, then will this not make it worse?

Comment: You could overcome this by not keeping everything in memory but writing to a different as soon as you can. File operations are slow but it should work.

Comment: #Martijn, I have a file of 78902 rows of data concerning houseprices, dates and postcodes. I have another file of ~1.7 mil which contains all the postcodes and their co-ordinates.

Comment: #Aleksander can you give a bit more explanation as to how? This is my first time using CSV files with python so I'm still figuring it all out.

Comment: @Scironic: And you are looping over both? That's 134+ trillion comparisons.

Comment: @Scironic `a=cvs.writer(someFile); a.write('your string or list if you use a.writerow')` More docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: @Martijn. Yep That's why this first issue worried me so much. I've played with 100 and 800k which took a couple minutes, I was hoping the whole thing would be something I could leave on over night but it doesn't look that way...

Comment: Look at how much memory the process you're running this in uses. Speed is one thing but if it starts and does OK it should just keep going, as slow as it might be, but shouldn't stall.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it stalled. Is there an obvious way to tell?

Comment: Let's stop dancing around the bush (to mix metaphors). If you post your code we might be able to make concrete suggestions. :)

Comment: @unutbu I've added it in for those who are interested. - Although a fair amount is surplus to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main bottleneck is in your `convert_postcodes` function:

```
for row in range(len(file)):
    for line in range(len(postcodes)):
```

If there are `N` items in `file` and `M` items in `postcodes` then this double-loop requires `M*N` iterations.

Instead, loop over the items in postcodes *once* and save the data mapping postcodes to longitude/latitude in a `dict`. Then loop over `file` *once* and use this dict to supply the desired data for each item in `file`. This will complete the `M+N` iterations:

---

```
def convert_postcodes(postcode_path, file_path, output_path):
    postcodes = dict()
    with open(postcode_path, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            code, lng, lat = row[1:4]
            postcodes[code] = [lng, lat]
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fin, open(output_path, 'wb') as fout:
        reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            code = row[3]
            row.extend(postcodes[code])
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful! I haven't done any work with dictionaries yet so it will be fun to play around with them. I'll give this a go in the morning and hopefully get it all running smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that looking up all codes in all files, that makes a huge number of comparisons.

You could try to save that in a dict, with the postral code being the key.

Comment: Doesn't Python access dictionaries at random? If so wouldn't it possibly take longer to find the right key? I did consider using a dictionary but wasn't sure it would be much better.

Comment: No, dictionaries display contents in a seemingly random order, but access is highly efficient. That's what they do, efficiently map a key to a value ford future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should use the sqlite3 module, load the csv files in there, and use SQL to do the join?

Comment: Never used SQL before so I don't know anything about it! It's one of the languages on the list to learn though.

Comment: It's not hard. You can do it! And sqlite is fast.

Comment: SQL is also key value, so let the OP play with dicts first.

Answer (score 2):

looping through all of this data is inefficient.

One quick and dirty solution is to use SQLite or some other relational data store, to which you can apply an index (if this doesn't fix your problem straight out).

for this and other solutions, you write a quick test using timeit() on each option, and increase the data size to discern the response.

Comment: No idea how to use SQL as I haven't touched it yet. Although I reckon I will be soon.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be much more efficient if you use `dict()` instead of `list()`. General algorithm:

1. Load data into 2 dictionaries: one for coordinates and another for you info. Both have postcode as the key.
2. Iterate through shortest of these dictionaries and for each postcode find item with the same postcode in large dictionary. Save matched postcode and coordinate somewhere.

The thing is that `dict()` has O(1) [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for getting by index, whereas `list()` has O(n) by searching (which is almost the same as to do another loop). For big data this makes a huge difference, in fact you do not need double loop.

Comment: I haven't heard about time complexity before but it makes some sense... That said, my key list (the one with the postcodes and co-ordinates together) is sorted, it's only my other datasets which aren't

Comment: If you use lists you need to whether search with O(n) or iterate with O(n). Sorting gives some advantage if you use it correctly (for example with bisect module), but dictionaries in this case much more efficient. You do not need to use sorting using dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and give it a go with one of the above suggestions (reading and writing line by line, instead of all at once)

Comment: @Scironic O(1) means that it takes the same amount of time no matter how much data you have. O(n) means that it will about twice as long for twice the data.